# enhanced 3d cursor. ''..blender redraws itself..''

Tags: add-on

This addon can show/hide the 3d cursor. When you mouse over on the button it says: 
[image]

Does that mean that it takes a lot of CPU usage to compute the addon and in general slows down the application ? Asking this because I have a really turtle computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. When you want to hide the 3D cursor then i would suggest to use the custom Blender build from fjuhec where this is better implemented. https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?370568-Custom-Build-Blender-pigeon-v2-78a-%28October-27th%29&highlight=custom+blender+build